# LINQ to DataSet group by with specific column

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I have a dataset with following table

```
id      domain        email
1      google.com     av@et.org
2      apple.com      gopal@jt.com
3      abc.com        av@et.org
4      global.com     av@et.org
5      local.com      gopaljite@gmail.com
6      xyz.com        gopaljite@gmail.com
7      gpl.com        gopal@jt.com
8      mno.com        av@et.org
9      pqr.co.in      gopaljite@gmail.com
10     aad.com        av@et.org
```

Now I need output as following

```
Sr.      Email               Domain_Count
1       av@et.org             5
2       gopal@jt.com          2
3       gopaljite@gmail.com   3
```

How can I do this with LINQ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result=table.GroupBy(c => c.email)
                            .Select(group => new { 
                                  Email = group.Key, 
                                 Domain_Count = group.Count() 
                            }).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Domain_Count);
```

bind to GridView:

```
yourgidView.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I want to show this result for grid view & result also have "sr" column

Comment: It's Linq query result as you asked. you just need to bind result to the GridView. try to search `GridView DataBinding`

Comment: Thank you. I got what I need.

Comment: `var dt = global.tblTemp.Tables["domain"].AsEnumerable()                  .GroupBy(c => c.Field<string>("email"))
                     .Select(group => new
                       {
                          Email = group.Key,
                          Domain_Count = group.Count()
                       }
                  );
     GridAll.DataSource = dt.ToList();